gparted on server without GUI is not starting
Unable to run gparted on fresh installed ubuntu 24.04.1 server (connecting with Xshell + Xmanager on my windows desktop).
If runt from regular user, error "Error executing command as another user: No authentication agent found." is displayed.
If runt from sudo - "(gpartedbin:1848): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:35:15.742: cannot open display: localhost:10.0".
Xshell is configured to forward X connections to Xmanager, xshell options about auth agent doesn't make a change.
Both 22.04.5 and 24.04.1 show the same behavior.

The server must have a GUI installed. Without GUI you can only use parted.

It is much easier to run gparted via the local monitor, the console, instead of via X. You can have a temporary GUI in the server if you install some tools. See this link. The need for elevated permissions makes it problematic to run gparted via ssh. Anyway, you should avoid running the GUI except when you really need it for some task.

Usually you have no need in local GUI on headless server to run GUI applications remotely. As mentioned, I have Xmanager (X server) on my desktop. What's wrong with gparted, or, with Ubuntu server, or, with my setup?

Also, xterm is started remotely on VMs above remotely without any problem, nm-connection-editor is starting from xterm (but only as unprivileged user, sudo - failing), but not from ssh session, gparted - not starting in any. I'd suppose that some services/configs are not listed and installed as gparted dependencies.

I have noticed that gnome applications are not happy to run via ssh. For example, xterm works for me, but not gnome-terminal. I must admit that I don't know why. There is the extra problem that gparted needs elevated permissions, and I think X via ssh is not considered secure. So there might be a deliberate tweak to prevent that (only guessing). Would it be possible for you to run gparted locally instead of via the network? Or would it be possible (maybe not convenient but anyway) to run the text tools parted or fdisk or gdisk instead of gparted?

No, that's not the option - this is headless server without GUI. I think there should be way to run gnome apps remotely on headless server without GUI installed. And, earlier, I was able to do so, at least with nm-connection-editor. May be it was with xming, instead of xmanager.
